# MYSQL Duplicate entry 1 for key 'PRIMARY' when importing to another table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to import some value from a table to another table, the problem is that the 2 tables have a primary column id

So when I do `INSERT INTO tab1 (SELECT * FROM tab2)`

*Duplicate entry 1 for key 'PRIMARY'*

It says I can't because the id 1 already exists,
I don't really care about conserving the id, I just want to insert it at the end of tab1

So I had the id to do this (without the id column):

`INSERT INTO tab1 (SELECT col2,col3 FROM tab2)`

...etc but it says *Column count doesn't match value count at row 1*

How can I do to just insert evrything with a new id?

thanks in advance

Comment: Try by using the extended INSERT version by specifying the columns to insert first and then provide the VALUES.

Comment: `INSERT IGNORE INTO tab1 (SELECT * FROM tab2)`. Duplicates will be ignored. Or you can do what @cen suggested, which is what I would have done.

Comment: If you don't care about that column being unique, remove the unique constraint from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

`INSERT INTO table1 (col2, col3) SELECT table2.anothercol2, table2.anothercol3 FROM table2;`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html

Answer (score 0):

If you can alter the stucture of table 'tab1' you could set in 'tab1' an auto-increment field for primary and the other two fields accordingly to 'tab2'.

`INSERT INTO tab1 (SELECT col2,col3 FROM tab2)` should work then.

Comment: This would only work if `id` was at the end of the table. Otherwise, as cen mentioned, specifically targeted `insert` would be required.

Comment: It was already on auto increment, but there was the error I said abou the column doesnt match...etc